# New command for merging 2 \includegraphics commands with text inbetween

Tags: graphics

I´m trying to merge two custom `\includegraphic` commands. The first command inserts a `-->`, the second one a `<--`.  It basically looks like this:

> -->This is an an example<--

How do I create a new command that enables me to include both arrows and still enter an arbitrary text?

Currently, my code looks like this: `\fa "Some Text \ba`.

`\fa` includes the front arrow using the `\includegraphics` command, `\ba` the back arrow. My aim is to combine both commands in one, while still being able to add some text inbetween.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hey, I can´t provide you with a MWE, since alle files are referenced via \input. Thus, my "main" latex filex bareley contains anything. And most commands are custom and company specific ( I can´t post my companies files). Basically, I am just asking what I have to do to merge \includegraphics{....} Some Text \includegraphics{...} into one, custom command.

Comment: @JLDiaz: Using the paramater [1] would require a specifc default value, wouldn´t it? I´mt trying to use to images to frame a sentence, almost similar to a box (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes).

Comment: @DanielKeyes: No normal parameters don't need or have default values, only optional parameters do.

Answer (score 2):

If I undestoood correctly your requirements, the way to do it is to define a macro which accepts one parameter which will be the "custom text".

You can use TeX's `\def` primitive to define the new command, or LaTeX's `\newcommand`. In general, the later is prefired because it checks if the macro you are defining already exists, and then refuses to define it again and issues an error. For your question, the answer would be:

```
\newcommand{\faba}[1]{\fa#1\ba}
```

The new command is named `\faba`, it requires one (1) parameter (hence the `[1]`). Then it comes the definition. Inside the definition you can use other previously defined macros (such as `\fa` and `\ba` which are your commands for producing the arrows), and the special symbol `#1` which represents the actual value of the parameter (the custom text).

After this definition, you can write `\faba{This is an example}` in your text, and the command `\faba` will be expanded with `#1` equal to `This is an example`.

I guess that your "custom text" will consist in few words, not containing several paragraphs. In this case you can use `\newcommand*` (note the final star) to define it, as in:

```
\newcommand*{\faba}[1]{\fa#1\ba}
```

The use is exactly the same, with the difference that no `\par` (or blank lines) are allowed as part of `#1`. This helps you to detect earlier when you forget to close the right brace after the macro argument.

If you prefer TeX's `\def` primitive (discouraged), the syntax would be:

```
\def\faba#1{\fa#1\ba}
```

and it would be equivalent to the starred version of `\newcommand`, but without checking if `\faba` was already defined, but overriding it previous value instead. The use of the macro would be the same.